# Is the first fundamental form the outer product of $\nabla s$ for a surface $s$?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Take two $2$-dimensional vectors $\boldsymbol a:=(a_1, a_2)$ and $\boldsymbol b := (b_1, b_2)$.

The **[outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product)** of $\boldsymbol a$ and $\boldsymbol b$ is

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    a_1b_1 & a_1b_2\\
    a_2b_1 & a_2b_2 \\
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Now take a surface $S\subseteq\textbf{R}^3$ parametrized by $\boldsymbol s(u,v)$. The **[first fundamental form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_fundamental_form)** of $\boldsymbol s(u,v)$ is

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    \boldsymbol s_u \cdotp \boldsymbol s_u & \boldsymbol s_u \cdotp \boldsymbol s_v\\
    \boldsymbol s_v \cdotp \boldsymbol s_u & \boldsymbol s_v \cdotp \boldsymbol s_v \\
\end{bmatrix},
$$

which looks suspiciously like the outer product of $\nabla\boldsymbol s := (\boldsymbol s_u, \boldsymbol s_v)$ with itself.
(The dot $\cdotp$ stands for dot product of vectors.)

Does this make sense? Does it generalize to other settings, like higher dimensions, or surfaces not in parametric form?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix

Comment: There is perhaps a formal similarity here, but the resulting objects are different in flavor. The outer product of two vectors has rank $1$ and so the first matrix is always degenerate. On the other hand, (at a fixed point in $S$) the second matrix is the Gramian matrix of the bilinear form on $S$ induced by the Euclidean inner product $\Bbb R^3$ for the ordered set $({\bf s}_u, {\bf s}_v)$. At a regular point of the parameterization ${\bf s}$, this ordered set is linearly independent and so the matrix is nondegenerate.

Comment: Well you could post this as an answer... =)